# CSS : Is there a way to activate a hover element without activating the one below?

Tags: html, css, design-patterns

I know my question is hard to understand but I have made [a gif to explain my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4P6IT.jpg). I would like the menu to go above the horizontal bar without activating it.
CSS of the vertical menu :

```
.dropbtn {
    color: white;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn a {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 200px;
    z-index: 3;
    padding: 5px;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    z-index: 4;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn a {
    color: #333333;
}
```

CSS of the horizontal bar :

```
nav {
    margin: 27px auto 0;

    position: relative;
    width: 800px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #34495e;
    border-radius: 8px;
    font-size: 0;
}

nav a {
    line-height: 50px;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}

nav .animation {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    transition: all .5s ease 0s;
    border-radius: 8px;
}

a:nth-child(1) {
    width: 400px;
    z-index: 2;
}

a:nth-child(2) {
    width: 400px;
    z-index: 2;
}

nav .start-home,
a:nth-child(1):hover~.animation {
    width: 400px;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #39aeb4;
}

nav .start-likes,
a:nth-child(2):hover~.animation {
    width: 400px;
    left: 400px;
    background-color: #39aeb4;
}
```

As you can see, I tried to add some Z-Index properties to the menu but that didn't change anything.
Thanks for your help !

Comment: assuming `dropdown` to be the wrapper of the whole drop down menu, try adding `z-index` to the `dropdown`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the note from W3School just to remind you:

"An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order.
Note: z-index only works on positioned elements (position: absolute, position: relative, position: fixed, or position: sticky)."

Try adding `z-index` to `nav` so the navigation bar will hide behind the `dropdown-content`:

```
nav {
    margin: 27px auto 0;

    position: relative;
    width: 800px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #34495e;
    border-radius: 8px;
    font-size: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

You should include some related html for easier testing.

Answer (score 0):

The following might work or at least help you in the right direction:

Regarding Z-index. Try setting `z-index = 99 !important;` and see if it helps.

With Jquery, you can check if your dropdownmenu is visible, and then disable the animation of your sliding button.

```
$(".nav").hover(function(){
    if($(".dropdown-content").css("display") != "none"){
        $(.nav).stop(true).fadeTo(200, 1);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply increase the z-index of your dropdown item. It will solve your problem.

```
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 200px;
    z-index: 50;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: please inspect the dropdown-content and check its height, if height would be 0 then add some min-height. Looks like problem occur as your dropdown-content has not any height.